# Evaluating excel horizontal cell like evaluation in java

Tags: java

I am trying create an engine which will be eligible to evaluate a formula like in an excel sheet. For example SUM(A1:Z1) (Horizontal series), SUM(A1:A10) (vertical series).

For that I have to first determine all the cells for the series. For a vertical one it's quite simple. But I need help doing the horizontal one.

In the horizontal part the row number is fixed, but the column reference can vary to a wide range, like from AAA1 to ADZ1.

Kindly help me with your expertise to the best way to do this using core Java only.

I think I have to be more specific about the question. Please find below the specific question

I need a method where I will give the input as below and expecting output as below

***Input:*** "A1" (start of the cell), "BA1" (end of the cell)

***Output:*** A list containing below data

A1, B1, C1, .... , Z1, AA1, AB1, ... AZ1, BA1.

Comment: I think snvrthn is able to understand it, again I did not understand which is not clear in the question. Though let me give my expected input output precisely

Comment: Input: "A1", "D1"  Output: A1,B1,C1,D1, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these 3 methods,
if there are any problem please comment.

```
//get numerical value from the string (ex: AA from AA1)
private int getHorizentalPosition(String str) { 
    int result = 0;
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            result = result * 26;
            result = result + (c - 'A' + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//get string value from the numerical value
private static String getStringFormat(int horizentalIndex) {
    String s = "";
    while(horizentalIndex > 0) {
        int x = horizentalIndex % 26;
        if(x == 0) {
            s = s + 'Z';
        }
        else {
            s = s + (char)(x - 1 + 'A');
        }
        horizentalIndex = (horizentalIndex - 1) / 26;
    }
    return new java.lang.StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
}

//your out put
public String[] getHorizentals(String str1, String str2) {

    int first = getHorizentalPosition(str1);
    int last = getHorizentalPosition(str2);

    String[] res = new String[last - first + 1];
    for(int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        res[i - first] = getStringFormat(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to translate string of the column name (for example 'ADZ') to to the related column number, you can resolve this using number translation:

```
int index = 0;
for (Character c : columnName.toCharArray())
{
  int value = c.charValue() - 'A';
  index = index * ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + value;
}

for (int prevIndex = 1; prevIndex < columnName.length(); prevIndex++)
{
  index += Math.pow(26, prevIndex);
}
System.out.println(columnName + " " + index);
```